# Full-featured web framework/CMS for building web sites based on imported offline content

Tags: django, drupal, frameworks, content-management-system

I have done many sites in PHP, Django and Java and rather than building sites from scratch from the ground-up, I'm looking for a more full-featured web framework/CMS that I can basically setup and import my content pages into.

What's important is to have a plethora of ready to be plugged in widgets such as youtube, comments, google maps, etc.. instead of developing these custom using a low-level framework.

Essentially I'm looking for a development cycle consisting of:

1. Instantiate site
2. Choose a theme or design my own
3. Build the standard homepage, about, contact, etc.. pages manually preferrably using an editor.
4. Layout my leaf-page templates with side navigation, RSS feeds, ads, etc.. with an empty placeholder for imported content.
5. Run an external script that can take my data from an external source and essentially build all the leaf pages using url-friendly urls that I specify

In the end I should have a navigate-able site that is searchable.  A bonus would be to be able to re-generate my content pages using updated content or a new layout.

Low-level frameworks are excellent but for my purposes I'd rather have something that works out of the box that I can plug in new plugins like a calendar widget or a custom widget I develop.

So far I've considered Drupal and I wasn't able to find too many good examples on using its API (which apparently is xmlrpc based) to generate nodes.  I like Drupal though because it's relatively easy to develop new custom widgets.

Perhaps others can suggest other CMS/frameworks that I should consider?  I don't think Wordpress would suit my needs as it's more of a blog-style engine.

My languages of preference would be python but I can deal with PHP.

Comment: Have you looked at [django-cms](https://www.django-cms.org/en/)?

Comment: Hello, yes I did but I'm looking for a more full-featured solution with lots of plugins that work out of the box.  Basically something that does more of the groundwork for you in the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import content easily in Drupal, you can use the [Feeds module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) to have your Drupal pull content from external sources. Out of the box, Feeds supports RSS, Atom and CSV from local files of HTTP (with support for PubSubHubbub). But Feeds is quite flexible and [developer friendly](http://drupal.org/node/622700) and there is already a large number of [contributed plugins modules](http://drupal.org/node/856644). Feeds is not limited to importing content as Drupal nodes, it also supports user, taxonomy and, again, is very flexible on what to do with the imported data.

To push content from an external script, you can use the *core* XML-RPC interface, but the [Services](http://drupal.org/project/services) modules offers much more flexibility.